# Не создается полностью environment для некоторых веток (gitlab-ci)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Всем доброго!
В .gitlab-ci.yml задано создавать динамически окружение для превью примерно так.

```
PrepareEnv:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ci/some_script
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
    url: $reviewURL:$reviewPort
    on_stop: StopReview
  only:
    - branches
```

Проблема в том, что для ветки мастер оно работает как и ожидалось, создается environment, в нем есть данные последнего деплоя и URL открывается по кнопке. Для всех остальных веток - environment создается, но в нем "You don't have any deployments right now.", хотя если зайти в соответсв-ий билд, сверху красуется "This build is creating a deployment to review/develop". Что не так?

Comment: может проблема в some_script?

Comment: Не. Скрипт отрабатывает успешно, иначе бы и не спрашивал :) Читал, читал, перечитал - вроде бы разобрался. Если дальше по коду yaml какие-либо ветки завязаны на другие окружения, к примеру на `environment: sbx` указано `only: develop` - тогда динамическое окружение не формируется, пока не добавишь `except: develop`. Жаль, что в документации никак не выделено, все одним ровным стилем/текстом - совершенно не обращаешь внимания, что это обязательное условие. И совершенное непонятно почему тогда не формируется даже для ветки `feature-123`, хотя к ней не привязано никакого "статического" окруж-я